# How to prove the product rule in multivariable without chain rule?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

It's easy to prove in one variable functions $f:I\subset \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ but I tried in multivariable and I'm stuck.

Let $A$ be an open set in $\Bbb R^n$ and $a\in A$.
If $f,g:A\to \Bbb R$ are differentiable in $a$, then $f·g$ is differentiable in $a$ and
$D(f·g)(a)=g(a)·D(f)(a)+f(a)·D(g)(a)$

$f,g$ differentiable in $a$: $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)-Df(a)(x-a)}{||x-a||}=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{g(x)-g(a)-Dg(a)(x-a)}{||x-a||}=0$.

I started this way trying to prove it similar to one variable case:

$\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)-g(a)·Df(a)(x-a)-f(a)·Dg(a)(x-a)}{||x-a||}=\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(x)+f(a)g(x)-f(a)g(a)-g(a)·Df(a)(x-a)-f(a)·Dg(a)(x-a)}{||x-a||}=\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(a)\frac{g(x)-g(a)-Dg(a)(x-a)}{||x-a||}+\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(x)-g(a)·Df(a)(x-a)}{||x-a||}.$

In this last step, I know the first limit is zero but I don't know what to do with the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now two days later I've already solved it. The key is adding in $f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)-g(a)·Df(a)(x-a)-f(a)·Dg(a)(x-a)$ the terms

$-f(a)g(x)+f(a)g(x)$

and also

$-g(x)·Df(a)(x-a)+g(x)·Df(a)(x-a)$

so that the limit can be separated this way

$\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{{\color{red}{f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(x)}}{\color{blue}{+f(a)g(x)-f(a)g(a)}}{\color{red}{-g(x)·Df(a)(x-a)}}+g(x)·Df(a)(x-a)-g(a)·Df(a)(x-a){\color{blue}{-f(a)·Dg(a)(x-a)}}}{||x-a||}=\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)-Df(a)(x-a)}{||x-a||}g(x)+\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(a)\frac{g(x)-g(a)-Dg(a)(x-a)}{||x-a||}+\lim\limits_{x\to a} (g(x)-g(a))\frac{Df(a)(x-a)}{||x-a||}=$

$=0·g(a)+f(a)·0+\lim\limits_{x\to a} (g(x)-g(a))\frac{Df(a)(x-a)}{||x-a||}$

Since $\frac{Df(a)(x-a)}{||x-a||}$ is bounded by $|D_1f(a)|+...+|D_nf(a)|$, the limit is zero.

So $f·g$ is differentiable in $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is easier if you're fluent with big/little $o$ notation:

\begin{align*}
fg(a+h) &= f(a+h)\cdot g(a+h) \\
&= [f(a)+h\cdot D(f)(a)+o(\|h\|)]\cdot[g(a)+h\cdot D(g)(a)+o(\|h\|)] \\
&=f(a)\cdot g(a)+h[g(a)\cdot D(f)(a)+f(a)\cdot D(g)(a)]+o(\|h\|),
\end{align*}
which implies $f\cdot g$ is differentiable at $a$, and $D(f\cdot g)(a)=g(a)\cdot D(f)(a)+f(a)\cdot D(g)(a)$.

Comment: That's a good idea but I do want to continue the proof the way I exposed, please.